# How to bake ambient light?

Tags: unity, lighting, unity-urp, global-illumination

I'm working on an indoor maze-like scene, with the only illumination coming from a few static point lights set to either Baked or Mixed mode. Since there are no windows, I'm facing the problem that every spot in the map that's not hit by direct lighting, is almost pitch black. So you go around a corner and you are staring into blackness. This is not very realistic of course since in real life, your eyes adjust and you are able to see quite a bit. Upping indirect light bounces does not solve the problem. What *does* solve the problem, is ambient light. Without any lightmaps applied to my scene, I can toy around with the Environment Lighting; I set the color to white, and play with the intensity until I get the desired "darkness" in "dark" areas. So far so good. I then go and bake lighting which only results in all ambient lighting being lost. It's not baked into the lightmaps.

Is there some setting I'm overlooking? How can I get the Ambient Lighting baked?

I know that as a hacky solution, I could create a few directional lights that cast no shadows to emulate ambient lighting. But why include ambient lighting at all if you can't even bake it?

Comment: That's odd, the ambient light should still be applied after baking a lightmap. Are you also baking ambient occlusion, maybe? That would explain why it gets blocked.

Comment: Yes, I'm also baking Ambient Occlusion, but disabling that did not make a difference.

Comment: Whoops, turns out I was wrong, that is indeed the normal behaviour. It seems like it's not possible to keep the (physically incorrect) ambient light after baking the lightmap.

An option that might work acceptably in your case is to ditch lightmaps altogether, make the building not be static (so its ignored in the bake) and to use light probes to capture indirect lighting around the light sources., while keeping realtime lighting everywhere else.  It's not the best, but it could work.